# When a link is clicked, pull up and display that information

Tags: html

I am trying to figure out how to do some HTML. Basically what I want is: if the user clicks on "coupon" a section of the page displays it. But only if it is clicked on. I have no idea where to look for this or what the name of what I'm trying to do is. Can someone point me in the right direction? I have tried the `<a name="">` but that takes me to a spot that is already there.

Answer (score 0):

On most cases, this requires JavaScript. But you can still do it without script with the exception that the section must be visible at all time. The actual contents would be placed in separate HTML pages (i.e.: files). Below is a simple example:

`main.html` file:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
  <A HREF="content1.html" TARGET="section">Content 1</A><BR />
  <A HREF="content2.html" TARGET="section">Content 2</A><BR />
  <A HREF="content3.html" TARGET="section">Content 3</A><BR />
  <BR />
  <IFRAME ID="section" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="600" />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

`content1.html` file:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
  This is content 1
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

`content2.html` file:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
  This is content 2
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

`content3.html` file:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
  This is content 3
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The above `main.html` content section will be blank when the page is loaded. To set the initial content, change the `IFRAME` tag so it would be like this:

```
  <IFRAME SRC="content1.tml" ID="section" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="600" />
```

If you don't want to display the section when the page is loaded, you must use JavaScript like this example:

`main.html` file:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
  <SCRIPT>
    function showSection() {
      document.getElementById('section').style.display='';
    }
  </SCRIPT>
  <A HREF="content1.html" TARGET="section" onclick="showSection();">Content 1</A><BR />
  <A HREF="content2.html" TARGET="section" onclick="showSection();">Content 2</A><BR />
  <A HREF="content3.html" TARGET="section" onclick="showSection();">Content 3</A><BR />
  <BR />
  <IFRAME ID="section" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="600" style="display:none" />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```